# typeahead.bundle.js how to start searching by pressing ENTER on the dropdown suggestions?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, typeahead.js

I managed to make it do the search by clicking on the DropDown suggestions. But it does not respond when I press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

**app/assets/javascripts/custom.coffee**

```
$ ->
    movies = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        remote: {
            url: '/movies/autocomplete?query=%QUERY',
            wildcard: '%QUERY'
        }
    });

    $('#query').typeahead(null, {
        source: movies
    });

    $('.tt-menu').on 'click', ->
        $('#search_form').submit()

    $('.tt-menu').on 'keypress', (e) ->
        if (e.which == 13)
            $('#search_form').submit()
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have looked into the javascript file typeahead.bundle.js.

```
_onEnterKeyed: function onEnterKeyed(type, $e) {
            var $selectable;
            if ($selectable = this.menu.getActiveSelectable()) {
                this.select($selectable) && $e.preventDefault();
            }
        }
```

$e.preventDefault() have stop ENTER to trigger keypress event in custom.coffee. After removing it removing $e.preventDefault() I can select the suggestion from the dropdown list and make it search instantly.
So the code should look like this:

```
_onEnterKeyed: function onEnterKeyed(type, $e) {
            var $selectable;
            if ($selectable = this.menu.getActiveSelectable()) {
                this.select($selectable);
            }
        }
```

Also I have to remove the code below completely:

```
$('.tt-menu').on 'keypress', (e) ->
    if (e.which == 13)
        $('#search_form').submit()
```

Now Everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it does not work your `$('#search_form').submit()` maybe you want to do:

```
 $('.tt-menu').on 'keypress', (e) ->
        if (e.which == 13)
            $.post('/movies', {your_model: {your_field1: 'test', your_field2: 'test2'}}; )
```

Actually you can test this on my production server https://sprachspiel.xyz, I tested in development.

I went to the homepage (https://sprachspiel.xyz) and opened with `f12` my javascript console. Then in the javascript console I posted the following code:

```
$.post('/subscription', { subscription: {email: 'test1@email.com'}});
```

This code makes a `post` request to my backend, passing parameters to my controller with the following structure `{subscription: {email: 'test1@email.com'}}`

This are my routes

```
subscription POST /subscription(.:format) subscription#create
```

My Subscriptions Controller has a `create` action that saves the subscription, but most important has the following `strong params` in a private method

```
def subscription_params
  params.require(:subscription).permit(:email)
end
```

I was lucky on the first try and I was able to write the jquery `.post()` request correctly, but in case you don't now how to structure your params, you just set a breakpoint on your server application code, `subscription_params` to see what is wrong there.

When you perform the request, your server will stop on the `binding.pry`

I tested, My server creates a new entry in my `db`

```
Started POST "/subscription" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-11-01 16:32:14 +0100
Processing by BuildingsController#createSubscription as */*
  Parameters: {"subscription"=>{"email"=>"test1@email.com"}}
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "subscriptions" ("email", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["email", "test1@email.com"], ["created_at", "2017-11-01 15:32:14.790279"], ["updated_at", "2017-11-01 15:32:14.790279"]]
   (19.8ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 200 OK in 26ms (ActiveRecord: 20.6ms)
```

but if you do this, you should make sure that your js somehow shows error messages

Comment: Sorry maybe I haven't made my question clear enough. The issue is when I pressed ENTER it never trigger `keypress` event. But I don't have problem with submitting the form itself. I have just found the cause for the problem in typeahead.bunlde.js. I have to remove e.preventDefault() on method _onEnterKeyed. I will write the answer below.